# How to side background image for small screen size using tailwind css and reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a background image and I am trying to remove the background image for small screens. I am using tailwind css with react.

I know there is a lot of question but that  doesn't fit for my requirements.

As i had complex background of multiple SVGs for that reason i created the class in index.css previse is here [image]

and then i used it in react component as follows: [image]

This work fine but now i want to remove the image for small and i don't now how to do it that is why i am postin question here.

Comment: Screenshots of code is hard to work with. Creating a small example of your problem using a tool like this can help https://play.tailwindcss.com/

Answer (score 1):

As `tailwind-css` uses mobile-first breakpoint system, you need to specify `bg-pattern` class to only large-screen sizes like `:md`, `:lg`,`:xl`

So change your `div` to:

```
<div className={`md:bg-pattern ...`}
```

So now your `bg-pattern` class is applied to only screen sizes of `:md` and above.